# Run a command with the argument from the last command

Tags: command-line, bash

When running commands, sometimes maybe you need to run a command with the  argument from the last command. How can you do this?

Of course, excepting the use of the arrow keys and <kbd>Del</kbd> keys: <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>...<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>...<kbd>Del</kbd>`<new_command>`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

For example, if you run this command:

```
mkdir long_path_here/new_dir
```

most likely you'd want to go in the recently created directory. You can do this using next "shortcuts":

- `cd` <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> - type `cd` and after press <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>.</kbd> (not in the same time). If the previous command has no arguments, you will get the previous command itself.
- `cd !*` - in this case you will get all arguments from the previuos command.  If the previous command has no arguments, you will get nothing.
- `cd` <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> - type `cd` and after press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> (in the same time). In fact, using this way and continuing to  press <kbd>.</kbd> (without to release <kbd>Alt</kbd>), you will get the last argument for every command from history. If a command has no arguments, you will get the command itself.

In general: `<command>` <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> or `<command> !*` or `<command>` <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: wow, you saved me hundreds of hours i would have ended up wasting in next couple of years

Answer (score 50):

There are a few shortcuts if you want all of the arguments from the previous command, or just the last argument.

- For all of the arguments: `<command> !*`
- For just the last argument:
  `<command> !$`

Examples:

```
ls foo/ bar/
ls !* # Gives the results of ls foo/ bar/

ls foo/ bar/
ls !$ # Gives the results of ls bar/
```

If you want a single argument from a list of arguments from the previous command, you can use `<command> !!:<argNumber>`

Example:

```
ls foo/ bar/ baz/
ls !!:2 # Gives the results of ls bar/
ls foo/ bar/ baz/
ls !!:1 # Gives the results of ls foo/
```

Comment: You only need one `!` in the single arg version, e.g., `!:2` . Assuming default bash.

Comment: You can also use `!^` in place of `!:1`.

Answer (score 10):

Mentioned `!*` and `!$` is a good thing, but when you need to do a little editing readline shortcuts come to help!

For instance, instead of the countless <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>...<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>...<kbd>Del</kbd> you can just press <kbd>↑</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>(jump to the start of the line)
<kbd>Alt+d</kbd>(delete to the end of the word)

For more info `man readline` and search for `Default key bindings`.

Answer (score 6):

To take the `n`th argument from your previous command, type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`n`+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>.  For example, after:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

typing `echo` followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> will give you this at the next prompt:

```
$ echo 2
```

The "screenshot" after you've hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> is:

```
(arg: 2) echo
```

You can repeat <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> multiple times to get the `n`th argument of previous commands in succession.

Another useful idea is to define alias `r="fc -s"`.  Then, you can do command substitutions:

```
$ echo 1
1
$ r echo=history
history 1
27755  history 1
```