# How to use some of the arguments of a previous command without retyping

Tags: command-line

Back to [Run a command with the argument from the last command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304830/run-a-command-with-the-argument-from-the-last-command). This post explained how to use previous commands argument in the new command.

My question is how to iterate among those arguments?

**For example:** just example not this needed

suppose I create two directories dir1 and dir2

```
mkdir dir1 dir2
```

I want to move `dir1` to `dir2` without retyping the arguments again. This is very handful when dealing with complex arguments or long paths.

The simplest command is needed

**UPDATE**

Suppose I have a command

```
mkdir arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 ... argn
```

I want to move `arg2` to `argn`

Comment: Up-arrow and change  the command?

Comment: you are talking about easy command like above. But Im asking in general when there are multiple arguments. I'll edit my question to show more

Answer (score 7):

I've found some interesting option of using `!`.

To get the arguments of previous command you can use:

```
!^        gives the first argument
!:n       gives the nth argument
!*        gives all the arguments
```

So in case of

```
mkdir arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 ... argn
```

To move `arg2` to `arg5`  for example use :

```
mv !:2  !:5
```

Comment: I can't live without the shortcuts `Alt+ .` to paste the last argument of the previous command or `Alt+Ctrl+y` to paste de first

Comment: @perdigueiro Nice tips friend